# Java Swing Panel/Button Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I  am creating a simple calculator GUI. Also,I am having an issue with resizing the help and exit button to about the size of the numbers button. I know I am doing something wrong with `GridLayout`, but not sure what it is.The code has no issues.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

```
public static final int WIDTH = 350;
public static final int HEIGHT = 500;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_CHAR = 4;

private JTextField single;
private JTextField equation;
boolean setBlank = false;
Double result;
String resultStr;
String verifyAction = "";
public Calculator()
{
    super("Calculator");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0,0,0));
    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    top.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    JPanel mid = new JPanel();
    mid.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
    //TOP
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    top.add(exit);

    JButton help = new JButton("Help");

    help.addActionListener(this);
    top.add(help);
    //MID
    single = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR);
    mid.add(single);
    equation = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR);
    mid.add(equation);
    //BOTTOM
    String [] key = {"7","8","9","+","4","5","6","","1","2","3","/","0",".","clear","="};
    for(int i = 0 ; i < key.length;i++)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(key[i]);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        bottom.add(button);
    }
    add(top,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(mid,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bottom,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing important information -- what GUI are you trying to create for starters? And what problems is your current code having?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"This is what it looks like:"*  Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 2):

This is a main problem: `setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);`. Don't do this as this can cause components that you don't want to have re-size do so. Instead all the components to size to their own preferred sizes by calling  `pack()` on the top window, the JFrame, after adding all components. Again this will let the GUI size itself.

Don't use GridLayout for the JPanel, but rather leave it BorderLayout, and play with your GUI component fonts. For example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static final int WIDTH = 350;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 500;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_CHAR = 4;
    public static final Font MY_FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 24);

    private JTextField single;
    private JTextField equation;
    boolean setBlank = false;
    Double result;
    String resultStr;
    String verifyAction = "";

    public Calculator() {
        super("Calculator");
        // setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);  // !! No ***************
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0, 0, 0)); // !! No ***************
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        JPanel mid = new JPanel();
        mid.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        // TOP
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setFont(MY_FONT);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        top.add(exit);

        JButton help = new JButton("Help");
        help.setFont(MY_FONT);

        help.addActionListener(this);
        top.add(help);
        // MID
        single = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR);
        single.setFont(MY_FONT);
        mid.add(single);
        equation = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_CHAR);
        equation.setFont(MY_FONT);
        mid.add(equation);
        // BOTTOM
        String[] key = { "7", "8", "9", "+", "4", "5", "6", "", "1", "2", "3", "/", "0", ".", "clear", "=" };
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(key[i]);
            button.setFont(MY_FONT);
            button.addActionListener(this);
            bottom.add(button);
        }
        add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(mid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Calculator().setVisible(true);
            ;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use pack but it resizes the gui to the whole space they are allotted. What I am wondering, is How I can make the help/exit button become the size of the number buttons at the bottom.

Comment: @DanielCalderon: Also, don't rely overly on GridLayout like you're doing. Use BoxLayout for instance.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried other layout but new to this. Teacher has only taught us GridLayout but I have read online that it is not really recommended. But not sure what use instead.

Comment: @DanielCalderon: I see, you're using GridLayout for the whole thing -- don't do that! You're then adding components with BorderLayout constraints that don't have meaning in this situation.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the first gridlayout and it seems to do more what I want. Ill look into the other forms of layout. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielCalderon: your teacher never told you not to learn about other layouts on your own, I'm sure -- read up on them!